# Swift4 - Check location authorization at any app startup

Tags: swift, location

the first time I run the app, the operating system automatically asks for location access.

If I deny and close tha app, at a new startup the operating system does not ask that again.

Is there a way (programmatically) to check location permission any time I run app and to show an alert if access is denied?

Thanks

Comment: I can see no solutions about checking permission and show an alert. Am I wrong?

Comment: Once you deny for very first time it will not show alert again, you need to redirect user to enable location, or you need to give proper alert so user can go manually and enable location.